# Issue with NSNumber in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a guessing game for the iPad, and I'm using an NSNumber to keep track of the number of tries the user has left in the game, called numberOfTries. The NSNumber is in a view-based file, and I first initialize it in the drawRect method, in order to draw boxes indicating how many tries the user has left. I initialize the number at an int value of 5, and it works at that point, but when I try to use it in another method within the class, like one that indicates whether the user is out of tries, it shows that it's already at zero by the time I enter the first guess. Here's the code:

```
//Game.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Game : UIView {
    NSString* equation;
    NSNumber* numberOfTries;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString* equation;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSNumber* numberOfTries;

@end


//Game.m
#import "Game.h"


@implementation Game

@synthesize equation, numberOfTries;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)hasLost
{
    int tryNumber = [self.numberOfTries intValue];
    return tryNumber <= 0;
}

-(BOOL)guessWithEquation:(NSString*)guessEquation
{
    int tryNumber = [self.numberOfTries intValue];
    if ([self.equation isEqualToString:guessEquation]) {return YES;}
    tryNumber--;
    self.numberOfTries = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tryNumber];
    return NO;
}

-(void)setEquationTo:(NSString*)theEquation {self.equation = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theEquation];}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.numberOfTries = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5];
    int halfwidth = self.bounds.size.width/2;
    int halfheight = self.bounds.size.height/2;
    int threeqw = self.bounds.size.width-(self.bounds.size.width/4);
    int threeqh = self.bounds.size.height-(self.bounds.size.height/4);
    int oneqw = self.bounds.size.width/4;
    int oneqh = self.bounds.size.height/4;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

    int tryNumber = [self.numberOfTries intValue];
    int point = oneqw-100;
    while (tryNumber > 0) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point, threeqh);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point+15, threeqh);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point+15, threeqh+15);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point, threeqh+15);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point, threeqh);
        tryNumber--;
        point += 30;
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

When it calls guessWithEquation, numberOfTries is already at 0, which is really confusing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not just let `numberOfTries` be of type `int`?

Comment: I tried doing that, too, but the same issue occurs. For some reason, it's just not holding it's value.

Comment: You can lose this line `[self.numberOfTries retain];` as you used `retain` in the `@property` otherwise you are leaking memory unless you double release it in `dealloc`. As far as the mutation of the value I would add a breakpoint for the setter (I think you can just add one at the `@synthesize` and you will get a break for all sets and gets but I've never tried it).

Comment: Okay, I checked it in the debugger, and numberOfTries goes to nil right after guessing with a function. I probably should have included that this the program is going back and forth between this file and a view controller. Could that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start out with `numberOfTries` uninitialised, and hence (because it is an instance variable and this is how Objective-C works) `nil`. Then, every time you redraw, you initialise `numberOfTries` to be a new `NSNumber` with value 5. And you throw in a spurious `retain` for good measure. How do you expect that to end well?

Initialise when you start, possibly in `initWithFrame` though you may also need to consider `awakeFromNib` if the view is loaded from an IB resource file. From then on, replace the value when it changes but do not recreate the object for no good reason.

And FFS never never never do this: `[self.something retain]`. What do you think that is doing? The property is already defined as `retain`. Trust that. This sort of thing is just making a mess.

Comment: I did start out by doing this in initWithFrame, and I still got the same problem, but I didn't use awakeFromNib, so I'll look at that. And I know the retain thrown in was stupid. I forgot to take that out. I was kind of getting desperate at that point ^_^;

Comment: @Kameron I do not mean to sound bad tempered -- though I obviously **am** -- but if you find yourself throwing in random method calls out of desperation that's a pretty good sign you should stop coding and **think** instead. Draw the chain of events out on paper if you have to. Programming is **not** voodoo. This stuff is deterministic. Things start out as X and only become Y as a consequence of some actual instruction. Don't guess at unfathomable rituals, work out what is going on. Here endeth another pointless rant.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. awakeFromNib didn't actually help much, so I just decided to store the number in the view controller, and now it's working fine. Thanks for the help!